# Splitting a AT command string using sscanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I have a problem with splitting a string using `sscanf()` in C.

I have

```
char sms[]="AT+CMGR=7+CMGR: \"REC UNREAD\",\"+213552830677\",\"\",\"14/11/29,21:20:36+04\"123456Cn50555202555";
```

and I want to get

```
char number[15] = "+213552830677";
char code[6] = "123456 ";
char cmd[2] = "Cn";
char arg[20] = "50555202555";
```

I use this code to do the split and print the results:

```
sscanf(sms,"AT+CMGR=8+CMGR: \"REC UNREAD\",\"+%12s\",\"\",\"14/11/29,21:20:36+04\"%6s%2s%s",tmp ,number ,code ,cmd ,arg);
printf("Temp: %s\r\nNumber: %s\r\nCode: %s\r\nCommand: %s\r\nArgument: %s\r\n",tmp ,number ,code ,cmd ,arg);
```

Comment: How come you don't show the regular expression, then?

Comment: sscanf(sms,"AT+CMGR=8+CMGR: \"REC UNREAD\",\"+%12s\",\"\",\"14/11/29,21:20:36+04\"%6s%2s%s",tmp ,number ,code ,cmd ,arg);
printf("Temp: %s\r\nNumber: %s\r\nCode: %s\r\nCommand: %s\r\nArgument: %s\r\n",tmp ,number ,code ,cmd ,arg);

Comment: That is absolutely not a regular expression. :| You should edit it into the question, remove mention of REs, and let us know what the problem with the `sscanf()` solution is.

Comment: can edit it for me pleas, i am new blue ;)

Comment: Sure, but of course I don't know what the problem is. That is the most important part of a question, and you're not telling us ...

Comment: @HamzaBENDALIBRAHAM , Try removing all the `\r` from the `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the `sscanf` format you forgot a conversion specification for the argument `tmp`; thus the input is assigned to the wrong objects.
- `char code[6]` and `char cmd[2]` are one short of space for the terminating null character, thus possibly other objects are overwritten.

After correcting these errors, e. g.

```
    char code[6+1];
    char cmd[2+1];
    char tmp[1+1];
    sscanf(sms, "AT+CMGR=%1s+CMGR: \"REC UNREAD\",\"+%12s"
                "\",\"\",\"14/11/29,21:20:36+04\"%6s%2s%s",
                tmp, number, code, cmd, arg);
```

it works.